# Intragram Graph API Webhooks

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, facebook-webhooks

I have read the documentation, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/webhooks but I am confused as to how the mentions API with the webhooks works and was hoping someone could throw some light my way.

I have successfully setup the hook, and my facebook app is configured to send data here.

I gather I Have to tell the the app that the facebook page linked with an instagram account wishes to subscribe by calling this:
POST graph.facebook.com/{facebook page id}/subscribed_apps which should then hit my hook everytime any linked page gets a mention in a media item or a comment?

This is the bit I am confused on and could really use some help!

Also, can I have multiple pages subscribe to the hook?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you figure this out or no 
i looked everywhere with no result

Comment: Please only post answers that provide an answer to the question